# GD rendered image not displaying apostrophes

Tags: php, gd

I have made a script which renders an image from a string. It is fine apart from the fact that apostrophes do not show. A space is where the apostrophe should be.

Any ideas?

Here is the rendering code: (the string is just normal text. Like a newspaper article)

```
$text = $_SESSION['article'];

$arrText=explode("\n",wordwrap($text,69,"\n"));//change number 75 here to check the wordwrap

$im = @imagecreate(650,2500); //creates an image (width,height)
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0); //sets image background color
$y=5; //vertical position of text

foreach($arrText as $arr)
{
  $white=imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255); //sets text color
  imagestring($im,5,15,$y,trim($arr),$white); //create the text string for image,added trim() to remove unwanted chars
  $y=$y+15;

}

imageantialias($im, true);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: Are those apostrophes like `'` or fancy curly apostrophes?

Comment: Odd, it worked for me. Are you sure you are using that apostrophe type?

Comment: Yeah it's that exact one. What other things could cause that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with some modifications :

- reduced height to 500px
- removed imageantialias that seems to be missing in my gd version

So :

```
<?php

$text = "this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test";

$arrText = explode("\n", wordwrap($text, 69, "\n")); //change number 75 here to check the wordwrap

$im = @imagecreate(650, 500); //creates an image (width,height)
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0); //sets image background color
$y = 5; //vertical position of text

foreach ($arrText as $arr)
{
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255); //sets text color
    imagestring($im, 5, 15, $y, trim($arr), $white); //create the text string for image,added trim() to remove unwanted chars
    $y = $y + 15;
}

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

It gave me :

[image]

So I have the ' myself. It is possible that in your system, or in your gd version, or so and so, `imagestring` function does not support the apostrophe.

Did you tried to use `imagettftext` instead of `imagestring` ? More than giving you apostrophes, you'll be able to customise your fonts very closely.

Your code becomes :

```
$text = "this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test this'is'a'test";

$arrText = explode("\n", wordwrap($text, 69, "\n")); //change number 75 here to check the wordwrap

$im = @imagecreate(650, 500); //creates an image (width,height)
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0); //sets image background color
$y = 5; //vertical position of text

foreach ($arrText as $key => $arr)
{
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255); //sets text color
    //imagestring($im, 5, 15, $y, trim($arr), $white); //create the text string for image,added trim() to remove unwanted chars
    putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
    imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 15, 16 + $y, $white, 'font.ttf', trim($arr));
    $y = $y + 16 + 4; // size of font + newline space
}

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Preview (with [this](http://home.fuz.org/tests/font.ttf) font) :

[image]